# Simple NodeJS Express App Cannot get /url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been at this for about an hour now and I have no idea what's wrong here. I can't access the url.
I made this Simple NodeJs Express app but when I access `http://localhost:3000/users/login` It gives an error `Cannot GET /users/login`

This is my
`app.js` File.

```js
const express = require('express');
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const userRouter = require('./routes/users');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));


app.get('/', indexRouter);
app.get('/users', userRouter);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

This is my `routes/index.js` file

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Welcome");
})

module.exports = router;
```

This is my `routes/users.js` file

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Login Route
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Login page");
})
// Register Route
router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Register Page');
})

module.exports = router;
```

Can anyone please tell me what's the issue here?

Comment: The issue is that `app.get('/users', userRouter);` will only match an exaact route of `/users`.  It won't match `/users/login` so thus it never sends that url to the users router.   Whereas `app.use('/users', userRouter)` matches any path that starts with `/users` so it will match `/users/login` and will send that url to the users router.  `app.use(path, ...)` matches any http method and any url that starts with the path.  That's nearly always what you want to use for middleware or routers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe instead of `app.get('/users', userRouter)` try `app.use('/users', userRouter)`

Comment: I think so too. Should be it, everything else looks fine!

Comment: How's it working with the `app.get('/',...)` . it displays the welcome message

Comment: I can't figure out why its working for that one specific case in index where you have just the server URL i.e ` http://localhost:3000/ ` . For all other cases its throwing error.

But it works perfectly is you use app.use() instead of app.get().
Basically we are telling our server `app` to use this router for this route. using 'get' there might throw some unwanted errors